# How to draw bar in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to draw bar chart for below data:

```
4  1406575305  4
4  -220936570  2
4  2127249516  2
5  -1047108451  4
5  767099153  2
5  1980251728  2
5  -2015783241  2
6  -402215764  2
7  927697904  2
7  -631487113  2
7  329714360  2
7  1905727440  2
8  1417432814  2
8  1906874956  2
8  -1959144411  2
9  859830686  2
9  -1575740934  2
9  -1492701645  2
9  -539934491  2
9  -756482330  2
10  1273377106  2
10  -540812264  2
10  318171673  2
```

The 1st column is the x-axis and the 3rd column is for y-axis. Multiple data exist for same x-axis value. For example,

```
4  1406575305  4
4  -220936570  2
4  2127249516  2
```

This means three bars for 4 value of x-axis and each of bar is labelled with tag(the value in middle column). The sample bar chart is like: 
    http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html

I am using matplotlib.pyplot and np. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the tutorial you linked to, but it's a bit tricky to shift them by a nonuniform amount:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, label, y = np.genfromtxt('tmp.txt', dtype=int, unpack=True)

ux, uidx, uinv = np.unique(x, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
max_width = np.bincount(x).max()
bar_width = 1/(max_width + 0.5)

locs = x.astype(float)
shifted = []
for i in range(max_width):
    where = np.setdiff1d(uidx + i, shifted)
    locs[where[where<len(locs)]] += i*bar_width
    shifted = np.concatenate([shifted, where])

plt.bar(locs, y, bar_width)
```

[image: numbered]

If you want you can label them with the second column instead of x:

```
plt.xticks(locs + bar_width/2, label, rotation=-90)
```

[image: labeled]

I'll leave doing both of them as an exercise to the reader (mainly because I have no idea how you want them to show up).

Comment: Great.. This is what i want it.. By the way, can we add colour for each bar?